# Empty BSON_ARRAY() in mongo C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb

The following works with mongo C++ BSON() and BSON_ARRAY() macros:

```
  BSONObj cr4 = BSON("providingApplication" << "http://cpr2.com" <<
                     "entities" << BSON_ARRAY(
                         BSON("id" << "E1" << "type" << "T")
                         ) <<
                     "attrs" << BSON_ARRAY(
                         BSON("name" << "A5" << "type" << "T" << "isDomain" << "false")
                         )
                     );
```

However, if I try to use an empty BSON array for `attrs` field

```
  BSONObj cr4 = BSON("providingApplication" << "http://cpr2.com" <<
                     "entities" << BSON_ARRAY(
                         BSON("id" << "E1" << "type" << "T")
                         ) <<
                     "attrs" << BSON_ARRAY()
                     );
```

it doesn't work (it doesn't even compile).

Any hint on how to produce an empty array using BSON macros in mongo c++ driver, please?

Comment: Perhaps the macros are for convenient filling. Empty objects you can typically get directly like mongo::BSONArray() or mongo::BSONArray::empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `BSONArray()` solves the problem:

```
  BSONObj cr4 = BSON("providingApplication" << "http://cpr2.com" <<
                     "entities" << BSON_ARRAY(
                         BSON("id" << "E1" << "type" << "T")
                         ) <<
                     "attrs" << BSONArray()
                     );
```

Thanks Öö Tiib for the tip!